# Should I use the top or bottom margins when creating space between two sections?

Tags: html, css

I have question when my sections have spacing between each other.
Should I use top or bottom margin to resolve it with:
- Encapsulation
- Easy maintance
- Not to be confused
- Adapt with margin collapse
Thanhs so much!

```html
<div class="section-1" style="margin-bottom: : 10px;">
    ABC
</div>
<div class="section-2">
    DEF
</div>
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
    ABC
</div>
<div class="section-2" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    DEF
</div>
```

Comment: I will use margin top.

Comment: It depends on your context and desired layout. Given the code you've shown, there's no difference. I generally add bottom margin to all sections via a common class and then remove it from the last one with [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: Purely opinion based. The way you have portrayed it, it's the same from a maintenance and "confusion" perspective. I don't know what you're encapsulating here either.

Comment: You may want to show an example of that issue.

Comment: Hi showdev and A.Sharma, sorry you for not making it clear.
When I create some sections with some people, we use both of this.
The margin collapse make it not clear, and when we need to turn off some section, the spacing broken my page and i need to edit the next section or above section to adapt.
I just want to know what everybody usually use to standard our coding style.
Thanks every body so much!